# history.location.replace is not a function using react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In redux's `componentWillRecevieceProps` can I do redirect using react router? I did this

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.user.isAuthenticated !== this.props.user.isAuthenticated && nextProps.user.isAuthenticated) {
        console.log(nextProps.history)
        nextProps.history.location.replace('/dashboard')
    }
  }
```

But the error is at `nextProps.history.location.replace('/dashboard')` I also tried `this.history.location.replace('/dashboard')`

But when I `console.log(nextprops.history)`, the method is there. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this.props.history.push('/dashboard')`

Comment: Do a little change: `nextProps` instead `this`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal it doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 2):

`location` Object in `history` doesn't have this method. Check out the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history). It is directly accessible on `history`:

```
nextProps.history.replace('/dashboard')
```